# Decypt des-sunos5.7 ecncrypted file by using OpenSSL in Linux

Tags: linux, openssl, solaris

One of the shell scripts in our old Solaris 10 server uses below command to decrypt a file.

```
des-sunos5.7 -d -u -k password enc_filename.tar.gz dec_filename.tar.gz
```

Now we are migrating to RHEL 6 and have trouble in finding the exact command to decrypt the file. We receive this file from external source and i don't have the cypher they used to encrypt the file.

I have used below commands

```
openssl enc -d des3 -in filename -out filename;
openssl enc -d -des-cbc -iv 0 -d -in filename -out filename;
openssl enc -des-ede3 -iv o -d in filename -out filename;
```

I have also tried with -des-ecb, -des-cbc, -des-ede-cbc, -des-ede3-cbc, -desx-cbc, -des. All I get is "Bad magic Number".

```
$file des-sunos5.7
des-sunos5.7: ELF 32-bit MSB executbale SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC1 Extensions Required, dynamically linked, not stripped
```

As per various articles, i understand that i am not using correct decryption cypher here. Can anyone help here to find the correct openssl cypher which can decrypt the file which is encrypted with des-sunos5.7 on a RHEL6 server. we have OpenSSL 1.0.1e.fips installed on Linux server

Comment: `bad magic number` is because `openssl enc` defaults to 'password-based' encryption which derives the actual key from the password by a complicated process based on PBKDF1 using salt which must be in a header in the ciphertext. It *can* do PBE without the salt by specifying `-nosalt` but that isn't terribly likely to be correct for ECB and can't be correct for CBC (because OpenSSL follows original PKCS#5 in deriving the IV but @V's link says Solaris des does CBC with IV all-0).

Comment: Dunno. But OpenSSL tentatively claimed compatibility with Solaris des(1) until [that DES code was thrown out](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/24956ca00f014a917fb181a8abc39b349f3f316f). From old `crypto/des/INSTALL` file: *"des(1) should be compatible with sunOS's but I have been unable to test it."*.

Answer (score 2):

From the name, I'm guessing that is the des(1) command included with Solaris, that someone pulled forward from Solaris 7 to your Solaris 10 installation (unclear why, as it is also available out of the box from Solaris 10u4 and up, and in SUNWcry before).

des(1) encrypted data with single-DES, but the file format will not match OpenSSL's file format. the des(1) command is quite old. Solaris 10 included the encrypt/decrypt commands with modern ciphers as a replacement.

This article may help you discover more background:

https://blogs.oracle.com/darren/entry/encrypting_files_in_solaris_10

I would decrypt using the des command on Solaris, reencrypt using OpenSSL on Solaris and then transfer the files.  OpenSSL is available on Solaris 10.

Comment: OP is apparently receiving files on an ongoing basis but retiring the Solaris system -- although worst case you could keep Solaris in a VM on the RHEL, used only for this. That blog says single-DES and ECB or CBC with IV all-0 which helps, but doesn't say if the 'password' is actually the key or undergoes any (nontrivial) deriviation.

Comment: I should thank every one for their inputs. 
We had reached out sender of the file and asked them to use openssl for encryption. We got an answer saying that we can use ssh and there will be no need of any additional encryption on the file.